# Get account list from google business account using java

Tags: java, google-api-client

I am trying to get all account list from my Google business account using service account in Java.

```
private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

/** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static MyBusiness mybusiness;

public static GoogleCredential getCredential() {
    GoogleCredential credential = null;

    try {
        httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        // check for valid setup
        if (UrlConstant.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL.startsWith("Enter ")) {
            System.err.println(UrlConstant.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        String p12Content = Files.readFirstLine(new java.io.File(UrlConstant.AUTH_FILE_PATH),
                        Charset.defaultCharset());
        if (p12Content.startsWith("Please")) {
            System.err.println(p12Content);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                        .setServiceAccountId(UrlConstant.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                        .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage"))
                        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(UrlConstant.AUTH_FILE_PATH))
                        .build();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return credential;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {     
     GoogleCredential credential = ServerAunthication.getCredential();
     System.out.println(credential);
     // Calls Mybusiness.Builder to create a new instance named 'mybusiness'.
     mybusiness = new MyBusiness.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
                     "test").build();


     com.google.api.services.mybusiness.v3.MyBusiness.Accounts.List accountsList = mybusiness.accounts().list();
     ListAccountsResponse response1 = accountsList.execute();
     List accounts = response1.getAccounts();
```

But getting below error:

> Method ListAccounts not found for service mybusiness.googleapis.com